# How to change the review tab title and content in product page?

Tags: layout, template, review

I'm creating a plugin that will extend the review tab title and content in the frontend. So far I can display some text in the product details page using this in my layout file in `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\my\reviewcontainer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <block type="reviewcontainer/tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>my/reviewcontainer/tabs.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Which calls the template `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\my\reviewcontainer\tabs.phtml` which basically has and outputs:

```
<h1 style="color: #e2000a; font-size: 200px">Hey there!</h1>
```

Just bellow the `<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">..</div>`

How can I edit this script so that the above template changes the review tab title and content instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set title of review by `setTitle` function.

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
```

May there are issue in your code.

**Layout code is:**

```
       <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.reviews">
        <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>my/reviewcontainer/tabs.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Bal</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

**Or try this:**

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.reviews</name></action>
     <block type="reviewcontainer/tabs" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="my/reviewcontainer/tabs.phtml" after="additional">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviewsddddd</value></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, since I'm developping a plugin, is it possible to do this inside a controller or a PHP `Bloc/` file instead of the XML?